# Swift : Twitter Kit Shares Image from Video instead of actual Video

Tags: swift, twitterkit

I implemented the Twitter Kit SDK and followed all their instructions to share a video to Twitter. Here is the code I have:

```
func shareToTwitter(){

    var composer : TWTRComposerViewController?

    composer = TWTRComposerViewController(initialText: "#metronome", image: nil, videoURL: URL(string: (MainController.sharedInstance.mergedFileClip?.compiledfileURL?.absoluteString)!))

    composer?.delegate = self

    if (Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.hasLoggedInUsers()) {
        // App must have at least one logged-in user to compose a Tweet
        present(composer!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // Log in, and then check again
        Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn { session, error in
            if session != nil { // Log in succeeded
                self.present(composer!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Twitter Accounts Available", message: "You must log in before presenting a composer.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

It triggers the log-in successfully and Im able to compose a tweet, however, oddly, it shares an image from the video as opposed to the actual video. Im confident that the videoURL that I pass through in the parameter is the video URL, because I use that same URL to save the video to the users camera roll.

What could I be doing wrong?